# How to handle daylight saving time in Java using ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream?

Tags: java, serialization, dst, objectinputstream

I am passing a hashmap which contains date as

> 2019-03-08 00:00:00.0

to servlet and while reading hashmap at servlet side I am getting date as

> 2019-03-07 23:00:00.0

Its converting one hour back only in daylight saving period.How can I handle this in java ?

```
java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date();
d.setDate(06);
d.setMonth(02);
d.setYear(2018);
d.setHours(23);
d.setMinutes(59);
d.setSeconds(00);

ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(request.getInputStream());
java.util.Date obj=(java.util.Date)is.readObject();
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
Vector vector = new Vector();
vector.add(d);
objectOutputStream.writeObject(vector);
objectOutputStream.flush();
objectOutputStream.close();
```

While reading it from java class, Iam getting one hour less.

Comment: handle what exactly?

Comment: By including time zone in your date and code logic

Comment: I need to get exactly '2019-03-08 00:00:00.0' at servlet side instead of '2019-03-07 23:00:00.0'.

Comment: It looks like you are using the `Timestamp` class? That class is poorly designed and plays such tricks on you. Fortunately it’s also long outdated. Use a class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) for predictable behaviour.

Comment: Why are you using classes and methods that are deprecated since Java 1.2?

Comment: You’ve really found the old way of doing things. `Date` is long outdated too, and as @Lothar said the methods you are calling are deprecated exactly because they don’t work reliably across time zones as you have experienced. No one I know is using `Vector` anymore. Even serialization is on its way to deprecation.

Comment: Which time zone are you in where summer time (DST) is in effect on March 8?

Comment: To be fair the Date class itself really isn’t that bad as long as you know it’s basically nothing but a wrapper around an epoch and that it has millisecond resolution at best. It can be worked with though. I think the problem here has more to do with a basic lack of understanding of datetime in programming, probably including what to expect from toString.

Comment: @Ole Yes its effecting on March 8th, and to all, as our project is legacy, we have to use those depricated code. Is there any way to handle these issue ?

Comment: Hi Ole, Iam facing issue when my servlet is executing at 'US/Eastern' time zone, If my servlet is executing at 'Asia/Calcutta' timezone I didn't face any issue. Iam using Timestamp in my servlet.I really need both time and date also. Leaving apart my code, changing the date totally happens just while reading it from servelt end. For ex: if we pass date from client side to server side, the date is changing. Here the communication from client to server is happening through streams...Sorry for the delayed reply.

Answer (score 0):

A likely explanation how this may happen is if the server time zone setting doesn’t take summer time (DST) into account. As an example I am taking America/Asuncion time zone. Asunción is the biggest city and capital of Paraguay. Paraguay is at offset -04:00 during standard time, but at -03:00 during summer. Summer time was still in effect on March 8 and will be until March 24.

First a demonstration of what goes wrong:

```
    System.setProperty("user.timezone", ZoneId.ofOffset("GMT", ZoneOffset.ofHours(-4)).getId());

    // Send a timestamp from America/Asuncion time zone
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Asuncion");
    // Create the timestamp as March 8 at 00:00:00
    Instant testTime
            = ZonedDateTime.of(2019, 3, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, zone).toInstant();
    Timestamp ts = Timestamp.from(testTime);

    try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        try (ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(baos)) {
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(ts);
        }
        byte[] ba = baos.toByteArray();
        try (ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(ba))) {
            java.util.Date obj = (java.util.Date) is.readObject();
            System.out.println(obj);
        }
    }
```

For this simple demonstration we don’t need separate client and server code. I create a `Timestamp` object with a known date and time in the time zone in question, write it to an `ObjectOutputStream` and read it back from an `ObjectInputStream` using the same underlying bytes. What I get back is a `Timestamp` representing *the same point in time*. To demonstrate what happens when the receiver prints it, I have set the default time zone right at the top. I am using a constant offset of `-04:00` to demonstrate what happens when the server time zone does not take summer time into account. It prints:

> 2019-03-07 23:00:00.0

So the same result you got. This is because — confusingly — `Timestamp.toString` uses the JVM’s time zone setting for generating the string.

**How to fix?**

When we know that the `Timestamp` was sent from America/Asuncion time zone, we can use that time zone explicitly on the server:

```
            java.util.Date obj = (java.util.Date) is.readObject();

            ZonedDateTime timeAsSent = obj.toInstant().atZone(zone);
            System.out.println(timeAsSent);
```

> 2019-03-08T00:00-03:00[America/Asuncion]

Now the time agrees with what was written to the object output stream in the first place.

**The better fix**

If there’s any way you can, avoid the old classes `Date` and `Timestamp` completely. Those classes are poorly designed and play such tricks on you. They are also long outdated. Instead write a `ZonedDateTime` or an `Instant` to the object stream on the client side and of course read the same type on the server side. Then there will be no room for surprises.